# SVG scales differently in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 32%; float: left;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

<div style="margin: 0 2%; width: 32%; float: left;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

<div style="width: 32%; float: left;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera:
[image: Firefox]

This is what I get in IE9, IE10 and IE11:
[image: Internet Explorer]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried a bunch of different things: with/without svg width and height, with/without viewBox, with/without px, with/without floats...

--- EDIT ---

I got it to work, here is what I had to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SVG Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 32%; float: left; padding-bottom: 32%; position: relative;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

<div style="margin: 0 2%; width: 32%; float: left; padding-bottom: 32%; position: relative;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

<div style="width: 32%; float: left; padding-bottom: 32%; position: relative;">
<svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
<!-- bunch of svg code removed for brevity -->
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is where I found the info I used: http://demosthenes.info/blog/744/Make-SVG-Responsive

I'm not smart enough to explain why this works. Without the extra CSS, IE gets grumpy when you don't specify the svg width and height, but then that breaks responsive scalability in all the other browsers. I don't know why making the svg absolute makes IE happy.

Comment: did you set the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute in the `<svg>`? Do you set the final size (width/height) of the `<svg>` at some point, probably by css?

Comment: @philipp Thanks. Ya, I had tried just about everything that made sense to me. I boiled down my original code to what worked for FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.